# Javascript Date format as DD.MM.YYYY using Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get **DD.MM.YYYY** formatted date using `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` specifically?

A proper result example: 24.04.2023

I tried `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(new Date()).replace(/\//g, '.');` and it works fine. But, I want to know if any implementation uses **only** the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` method without the help of the `replace()` function or any other methods.

Comment: Poland use `DD.MM.YYYY` , so you could maybe do ->  `Intl.DateTimeFormat('pl').format(new Date())`

Comment: Like this? `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-CH').format()`

Comment: @Keith btw is there a list of timezones and their formats for reference?

Comment: Thank you @Keith @Josh!! Where can I find a reference for a list of locales?

Comment: Although these ways are tricky, but if there aren't any other ways, please post them as answers so I can up-vote and approve them.

Comment: If you want a specific format reliably, *Intl.DateTimeFormat* is not a good option. All you can do is find a language that correlates to the format you want and use that. Then hope that the CLDR doesn't change the format at some future time. Formatting a date as you require is perhaps 5 lines of code, written once. Why forgo that for any uncertainty at all?

Comment: @cmgchess—Intl formats are correlated to languages, not timezones (which may cover many regions with different languages).

Comment: @RobG, I agree with you. Tbh I wrote the formatting using `date.getUTCDate()+...etc` at first (like many open-source libraries), and someone told me what I did was wrong, and I had to use `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` for the custom formatting (which was weird to me)! And that made me post this question!

Comment: @AmirMohammadMoradi—it would be enlightening to know why the formatting approach used by pretty much every date formatting library out there is wrong.

Comment: Did you mean `date.getDate`, unless you really do want UTC time.  Do be aware of the differences, even in the UK where UTC is pretty much GMT, it's not the same as BST that the UK currently is in.

Comment: @Keith, Yes I wanted my use case's exact `UTC` timezone date.

Comment: In that case `Intl` wouldn't have been much use anyway, as it's for formatting locale time.  But for a 1 liner for UTC time ->  `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('.')`